# I am trying to run the tcpdump on remote machine using ssh using nohup

Tags: linux, ssh, tcpdump, nohup

I am trying to run the tcpdump on remote machine using ssh using nohup.

```
[support@sv4-haswell107-bqkp91500107-node-1 ~]$ nohup sudo  tcpdump -i lo port 2049 -s0 -w ./test.pcap >/dev/null&                                    
[1] 14286
[support@sv4-haswell107-bqkp91500107-node-1 ~]$ nohup: ignoring input and redirecting stderr to stdout

[support@sv4-haswell107-bqkp91500107-node-1 ~]$ 
[support@sv4-haswell107-bqkp91500107-node-1 ~]$ 
[support@sv4-haswell107-bqkp91500107-node-1 ~]$ ps -ef | grep -i tcpdump                 
root     14286 28830  3 00:30 pts/1    00:00:00 sudo tcpdump -i lo port 2049 -s0 -w ./test.pcap
tcpdump  14292 14286  1 00:30 pts/1    00:00:00 tcpdump -i lo port 2049 -s0 -w ./test.pcap
support  14325 28830  0 00:30 pts/1    00:00:00 grep --color=auto -i tcpdump
```

But When I try to run the same command using ssh , tcpdump is not running in background.

```
[support@sv4-haswell107-bqkp91500107-node-1 ~]$ ssh -tt -p 2222 support@localhost 'nohup sudo  tcpdump -i lo port 2049 -s0 -w ./test.pcap >/dev/null&'

Connection to localhost closed.
[support@sv4-haswell107-bqkp91500107-node-1 ~]$ ps -ef | grep -i tcpdump                                                     
support  25861 28830  0 00:28 pts/1    00:00:00 grep --color=auto -i tcpdump
```

Comment: Does `sudo` require a password?

Comment: No.. sudo doesn’t require password

Comment: Then the first test I'd run would be to remove `>/dev/null`, so it sends output & errors to nohup.out, and then look to see if that contains any useful indications of what's going wrong.

Comment: @GordonDavisson Thanks .

Answer (score 0):

After redirecting the output to a file.. tcpdump starts in background

```
ssh -tt -p 2222 support@localhost' /usr/bin/nohup tcpdump -i lo port 2049 -s0 -w ./test.pcap  > /tmp/no.log 2>&1 &'
```